# Delphi 10.3.3 , Android App AutoStart on Boot ( Android 8.x , 10.x )

Tags: android, delphi

I created a java file with following content :

```
package com.embarcadero.XLRBoot;
     
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
     
public class startup extends BroadcastReceiver
{
     
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
               Intent sintent = new Intent();
           sintent.setClassName(context, "com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity");
               sintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               context.startActivity(sintent);
        }
     
}
```

I have created a JAR file from this like this :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin>jar cf com-embarcadero-XLRBoot.jar "d:\Delphi XE 10\XLR Spider\Boot Receiver\com-embarcadero-XLRBoot.java"
```

My AndroidManifest.template looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="%package%"
        android:versionCode="%versionCode%"
        android:versionName="%versionName%"
        android:installLocation="%installLocation%">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="%minSdkVersion%" android:targetSdkVersion="%targetSdkVersion%" />
    <%uses-permission%>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="%persistent%" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="%restoreAnyVersion%" 
        android:label="%label%" 
        android:debuggable="%debuggable%" 
        android:largeHeap="%largeHeap%"
        android:icon="%icon%"
        android:theme="%theme%"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="%hardwareAccelerated%"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">

        <%provider%>
        <%application-meta-data%>
        <%uses-libraries%>
        <%services%>
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="%activityLabel%"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="%libNameValue%" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm" />
        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.XLRBoot"
                android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Registration is complete -->    
        <%activity%>
        <%receivers%>
    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

I have set following Permissions in Delphi :
[x] Receive boot completed
[x] Reorder tasks

I compile my App, Run it, stop it, reboot device. I get an error that it stopped.

In the logs I see following entry :

```
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.embarcadero.XLRBoot, PID: 2769
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.embarcadero.XLRBoot: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.embarcadero.XLRBoot" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.embarcadero.XLRBoot-OHpYv4loPMPls2q6DuLOLA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.embarcadero.XLRBoot-OHpYv4loPMPls2q6DuLOLA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.embarcadero.XLRBoot-OHpYv4loPMPls2q6DuLOLA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib/hw]]
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3174)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1675)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.embarcadero.XLRBoot" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.embarcadero.XLRBoot-OHpYv4loPMPls2q6DuLOLA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.embarcadero.XLRBoot-OHpYv4loPMPls2q6DuLOLA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.embarcadero.XLRBoot-OHpYv4loPMPls2q6DuLOLA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib/hw]]
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3169)
04-20 12:38:49.087  2769  2769 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 8 more
```

I obviously missed something, but what ?

Thank you for the help.

Regards
Robert

**UPDATE 4**

I removed the previous updates because I was a bit off . So this is how it seems like I need to properly create the files.

Generate Class File

```
javac -Xlint:all -classpath "c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-26\android.jar" "d:\Delphi XE 10\XLR Spider\Boot Receiver\0.2\startup\com\embarcadero\XLRBoot\startup.java" -d "d:\Delphi XE 10\XLR Spider\Boot Receiver\0.2\startup"
```

Generate JAR file :

```
jar cf "d:\Delphi XE 10\XLR Spider\Boot Receiver\0.2\startup\com\embarcadero\XLRBoot\startup.jar" -C "d:\Delphi XE 10\XLR Spider\Boot Receiver\0.2\startup\com\embarcadero\XLRBoot" startup.class
```

Delphi gives a EXEC(1) Exec Error.

Comment: Did you add the jar file to the libraries section of the project in the project manager?

Comment: Yes , it is added to Target Platform -> Android 32 bit -> Libraries -> com-embarcadero-XLRBoot.jar

Comment: The class name of your receiver is `com.embarcadero.XLRBoot.startup`, not `com.embarcadero.XLRBoot`. You need to fix that in the manifest

Comment: Changed it, I think I might be doing something wrong with the JAVA to JAR file generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1 :**

create src\com\XLR folder in your App Directory

there create the file BootReceiver.java with the following content :

```
package com.XLR;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
           Intent launchintent = new Intent();
           launchintent.setClassName(context, "com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity");           
           launchintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(launchintent);  
        }

}
```

**Step 2 :**

Under your App Directory create build.bat with following content :

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Compiles your Java code into classes.dex
echo Verified to work in Delphi 10.3.3
echo.
echo Place this batch in a java folder below your project (project\java)
echo Place the source in project\java\src\com\dannywind\delphi
echo If your source file location or name is different, please modify it below.
echo.

setlocal

set ANDROID_JAR="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-26\android.jar"
set DX_LIB="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\28.0.2\lib"
set EMBO_DEX="D:\PRG\20.0\lib\android\debug\classes.dex"
set PROJ_DIR=%CD%
set VERBOSE=0
set JAVASDK="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin"
set DX_BAT="C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\28.0.2\dx.bat"

echo.
echo Compiling the Java source files
echo.
pause
mkdir output 2> nul
mkdir output\classes 2> nul
if x%VERBOSE% == x1 SET VERBOSE_FLAG=-verbose
%JAVASDK%\javac %VERBOSE_FLAG% -Xlint:all -classpath %ANDROID_JAR% -d output\classes -source 1.6 -target 1.6 src\com\XLR\BootReceiver.java

echo.
echo Creating jar containing the new classes
echo.
pause
mkdir output\jar 2> nul
if x%VERBOSE% == x1 SET VERBOSE_FLAG=v
%JAVASDK%\jar c%VERBOSE_FLAG%f output\jar\XLRBoot.jar -C output\classes com


:Exit

endlocal
```

**Step 3 :**

now run build.bat and it will create the class and jar files in the Output Directory in your App Directory.

**Step 4 :**

Alter your AndroidManifest.template like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="%package%"
        android:versionCode="%versionCode%"
        android:versionName="%versionName%"
        android:installLocation="%installLocation%">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="%minSdkVersion%" android:targetSdkVersion="%targetSdkVersion%" />
    <%uses-permission%>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="%persistent%" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="%restoreAnyVersion%" 
        android:label="%label%" 
        android:debuggable="%debuggable%" 
        android:largeHeap="%largeHeap%"
        android:icon="%icon%"
        android:theme="%theme%"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="%hardwareAccelerated%"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">

        <%provider%>
        <%application-meta-data%>
        <%uses-libraries%>
        <%services%>
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="%activityLabel%"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="%libNameValue%" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.notifications.FMXNotificationAlarm" />
        <receiver android:name="com.XLR.BootReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Registration is complete -->    
        <%activity%>
        <%receivers%>
    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

**Step 5:**

Add the output\jar\XLRBoot.jar file to your Libraries inside Delphi and Run the programm.

**Step 6:**

After Run the Program Starts, Stop it Start it again . Now Reboot it will start. Turn Device Off and Turn On again and it will start.

Thank you.

SPECIAL NOTE FOR ANDROID 10 :

You must set the Permissions System Alert window in Delphi. And on the Phone under App Info -> Advanced enable the Display over other apps settings.

Comment: In your comment in the question, you said changing the manifest didn't work. You've changed the manifest here to correctly match the receiver class name

Comment: The way I generated the jar file was not correct as well.